# Up arrow key macro no longer works in chrome. (Send {Up})

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

After some update of chrome or maybe moving my script to a new computer I am no longer able to use a very simple macro for sending the ↑ and ↓ arrow keys.

My code:

```
!w::send, {Up}
!s::send, {Down}
```

I attempted adding return to the end of the line and reformatting but only got the behaviour for ↓ regardless of combination. even more odd was that the following code also made the page scroll down

```
!w::send, {Up} return
```

and

```
!w::send, {NumpadUp} return
```

I am more than a little confused how such a simple macro is not functioning. in only google chrome but fine in other applications. My current thought is that it may overlap with some active extension but I am only seeing a possible conflict with a smooth scrolling extension that shares the usage of the alt key. This however was active last time the macro was functioning and worked to enable smooth scrolling. Attempts with the extension disabled have not produced different results.

I have also altered the key trigger to be just "w" and this yields no result in chrome. Yet the original code functions within text fields in chrome. I think this is mostly an issue with google chrome but I cannot understand why sending the key does not function despite it working when pressing the actual direction keys.

EDIT: So another round of troubleshooting I tried switching to a guest user and the macro functions. there must be an extension that is taking priority over the macro functions. What remains confusing that is it does not appear to have any relation to which key combination I attempt to trigger it with. I will have to start blank and progressively re-enable everything to find out more about the interaction.

Comment: Try using the  `Sendinput` command instead of `Send`

Comment: seems to have no effect for numpad up or regular up specifically in chrome. still works for everything else